# uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Validateable::HashWithIndifferentAccess when running ActiveMerchant's unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I am trying to run the unit tests of the `ActiveMerchant` gem version 
1.4.1: `https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/tree/v1.4.1`

First I ran: rake -T and got the error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Validateable::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

I fixed that first error by adding:

```
gem 'activesupport', "=2.3.4"
require 'active_support'
```

at the top of the Rakefile`(https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/v1.4.1/Rakefile`). Note that I had to specify the exact version (I guess `HashWithIndifferentAccess` doesn't exist in later versions of `ActiveSupport).`

Now, if I run: rake test:units, I get the same error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Validateable::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Here is the task that it tries to run (in the same Rakefile):

```
  Rake::TestTask.new(:units) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/unit/**/*_test.rb'
    t.ruby_opts << '-rubygems'
    t.verbose = true
  end
```

How can I get rid of this error? Do I need to specify the activesupport gem inside the task?

Comment: Can you also add the whole stack trace from the error, please? You can get that with: rake test:units --trace

Answer (score 0):

`gem 'activemerchant' # =>  Ruby 1.9.2 / AM 1.12.x`

vs

`gem 'active_merchant' # => ? / AM 1.5.2`

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I use Ruby Entreprise Edition: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.2.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2009.10 if that's what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMerchant is on version 1.12.0, so 1.4.1 is quite old - have you tried this with the latest version?